# Serving image from string in http golang

Tags: image, http, go

I need to display image with HTTP GET but the thing is i can only use String as the response body.

So for example (headers:image/png, body:Aeacxxffsaf(encoded representation or whatever) )

It's more or less like this web https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter, but i want the string to output into image when using http GET.

Some code snippets explanations here:

```
//string that is generated from image (encoded)
encString := "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAANIAAAAzCAYAAADigVZl..."

//set http headers to png
//and assign the encString to the body
```

Is there any way for that? By using string only to serve image

Sorry if my question is a bit confusing but it is the best i can describe it, i have been searching for the answer since several days ago

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/#Encoding.DecodeString

Comment: i understand how to decode it, i have actually gotten the decoded string, but when i tried to send the decoded string with image/png header the image just won't appear

Comment: _Why_ can you only send a string? Which library are you using?

Comment: currently i am using serverless framework which only enable me to send string in the response body, i have been searching for a way to send image using only string

Comment: im still finding out whether it is actually possible or not, but i hope it is possible

Comment: That's just not how image serving works. A plain text string will *never* be rendered in a browser as an image without custom code decoding it first.

Answer (score 1):

You do that just like with any other content, just decode the base64 first.

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    encString := "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAANIAAAAzCAYAAADigVZl..."
    bytes, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(encString)
    if err != nil {
        // todo
    }
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/png")
    _, err = w.Write(bytes)
    if err != nil {
        // todo
    }
}
```

However, if you want to display it in browser without decoding, then you will have to do some client-side hacking.

Comment: is it possible to assign string, not bytes? because for some reasons i only can send string as my response. anyway i need it like this https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ4KIIaZS_OYnj32E1QVNlXu0Jai5GOl-1V8zzRA9CFE9i2qJRoeg

Comment: @DemiDust sure, you can write a string using io.WriteString(w, stringContent)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you interpret it on the other side. 
The encoded b64, b32, byte array, etc. string all represent the same pattern of bytes. 
To get it to display as an image on the other side all depends on how you interpret it from the other side.

EDIT:

I see what you mean now. Have a look at the [image/jpeg package](https://golang.org/pkg/image/jpeg/).

Sadly I don't have a code snippet to share with you right now, but with this you should be able to load your image onto a buffer and decode it to get an image.Image object.

Afterwards you can use that image.Image object to write it into your response body. Sadly I can't provide a code snippet right this second, but do let me know if it works for you.

remember to set your writer's appropriate header.

w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")

Comment: i need it to be showing like this only https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ4KIIaZS_OYnj32E1QVNlXu0Jai5GOl-1V8zzRA9CFE9i2qJRoeg